# ggplot filling each standard deviation a different color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been looking around online and I can't find a clear answer how to fill different sections under the normal distribution using ggplot and stat_function --> dnorm.

```
#Parameters 

mu = 18.7
sigma = 36.4
n = 168
x = c(mu - 4*sigma/sqrt(n), mu + 4*sigma/sqrt(n))
```

Here's what I have for the plot

```
ggplot(data, aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm,
                args = list(mean = mu, sd = sigma/sqrt(n)), 
                geom = "area", 
                fill = "steelblue")
```

[image: Plot]

What I want is to fill the first standard deviation one color, the second another color, and so on.
I've also noticed that the curve does not appear smooth. Any reason why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the "curve does not appear smooth" - `stat_function` has an argument `n` for how many points along the curve to use. It's default is 101. You can use higher values of `n` to make the curve smoother.

Comment: Filling different regions with different colors suggests that the regions must be different. As crazy as that may *sound*, realize that your code above is making just one region. BTW, *please* test the code you post to questions. In this case, `Error:   You're passing a function as global data`, because you're suggesting that `data` is a `data.frame` object when to the rest of us, it is the `utils::data` *function*.

Comment: I completely forgot to data the data frame section of code, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get different colors with `stat_function`, you can use the `xlim` argument, e.g.,

```
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm,
                args = list(mean = mu, sd = sigma/sqrt(n)), 
                geom = "area", 
                fill = "steelblue", n = 1001) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm,
                args = list(mean = mu, sd = sigma/sqrt(n)), 
                geom = "area", 
                fill = "chartreuse", n = 1001, xlim = c(mu - sigma / sqrt(n), mu))
```

That could get tedious, so if you want every standard deviation different it would be simpler to generate the function data and use `geom_area` directly:

```
sim_dat = data.frame(x = seq(x[1], x[2], length.out = 1001))
sim_dat$y = dnorm(sim_dat$x, mean = mu, sd = sigma / sqrt(n))
sim_dat$sds = cut(sim_dat$x, breaks = c(-Inf, mu + sigma / sqrt(n) * (-3:3), Inf), labels = setdiff(-4:4, 0))

ggplot(sim_dat, aes(x, y, fill = sds)) + geom_area()
```

[image]